# How can I save this data to a txt using pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, json, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

up here has a nested structure where it starts with

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text (message, user_markup=None):
```

right after that comes the nested structure and this function would be inside it

```
def wallet(message):
    if message.text == 'Wallet NST':
       sent=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """Crypto currency is an Ethereum token.
    NST Smart Contract Token Address is as follows:
    (0xD89040Ac9823B72F64d71f66Fa2DeAE7C8520671).
    Please make sure you are using the right smart contract or your funds may be irretrievably lost. \n
    INFORM YOUR WALLET NST(NEW SOLUTION ) :""")
      bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, salva)

def guard(message):
    archive=open('oriondb.txt', 'w')
    archive.write(int(messagefrom_user.id)  + message.from_user.username + message.chat.text )
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'CARTEIRA SALVA COM SUCESSO!')
    bot.register_next_step_handler( handle_text)
```

I would like to save the answer to a txt file or a database how can i do this using pytelegramBotAPI?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def wallet(m):
cid = m.chat.id

if m.text == 'Wallet NST':
   bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, salva)
   sent=bot.send_message(cid, """Crypto currency is an Ethereum token.
   NST Smart Contract Token Address is as follows:
   (0xD89040Ac9823B72F64d71f66Fa2DeAE7C8520671).
   Please make sure you are using the right smart contract or your funds may be 
   irretrievably lost. \n
   INFORM YOUR WALLET NST(NEW SOLUTION ) :""")


archive=open('oriondb.txt', 'a')
archive.append(str(cid)  + m.chat.username + m.chat.text )
bot.send_message(cid, 'CARTEIRA SALVA COM SUCESSO!')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.